# Matrix spiral traversal subset sum

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given a matrix find the subset sum while traversing matrix in spiral form.

Was asked this question in an interview. Figured this is a combination of traversing in spiral form in O(n) and find subset sum (exponential or DP solution). But unable to think how can i combine both solution. Any pointers are appreciated.

EDIT: No extra space allowed.

Comment: If you can use `O(N)` extra space, you can despiral the matrix into a flat array and apply subset sum to that. Alternatively, you just need an accessor to the matrix which converts `i=[0,N)` to the appropriate 2D coordinates.

Comment: thought about it but extra storage space is not allowed.

Comment: Is `N` the side length of the matrix (assuming it is square) or the number of elements in it?

Comment: It's not clear (to me) what you're asking. "Subset sum" usually refers to finding a subset of a set that sums to zero. How does a spiral traversal of a matrix relate to that? A subset is a subset no matter what order you traverse the elements in. Also, you mention "exponential or DP solution" -- usually an exponential solution would run in at least O(log n) space and a DP solution in O(n) space, but you say that no extra space is allowed (by which I assume you mean O(1) space).